# Session doesn't exist in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot to develop an application, Here I want to show the "**Name and Image**" of the logged in user, So I use session to pass name and image after authentication. Its working *if any user enter the user credentials (in login page) or if any logged in user directly type the URL **for few minutes** (www.abc.com/this/url)*. But after few minutes, session name and Image *are not visible*(session expired) but other function are working with that session. My code is

```
@Component
public class SecurityHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        User user = userService.findBySSO(userName);        

        session.setAttribute("userName", user.getFirstName());  
        session.setAttribute("imgPathh", user.getImagePath()); 

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/dashboard/index");

    }

}
```

**Common jsp page**

```
<h2><c:out value="${userName }"></c:out></h2>
```

I want to know why this session variable doesn't work even after few minutes after the authentication ( anyhow if we type the URL directly, it should pass this authentication, am I correct?)

***Update 1.***
**Security config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    SecurityHandler securityHandler;

    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());


    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers() // antmachers 
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(securityHandler).loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
        .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionFixation().migrateSession()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED); //always, IF_REQUIRED,never ,stateless 

        http.logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        authenticationProvider.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false);
        System.out.println("Error in DaoAuthenticationProvider");
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
                "remember-me", userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
        System.out.println("Error in PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices");
        return tokenBasedservice;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
        System.out.println("Error in AuthenticationTrustResolver");
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using `spring-security`? What is your security configuration?

Comment: Try to set the  session timeout in web.xml

Comment: @VPK yes, I updated my code here, please check

Comment: What do you mean by `but other function are working with that session`? Does only `userName` and `imgPathh` are not available in session?

Comment: does it work without security?

Comment: @VPK it means, I can go insied and do other works in that application, but it doesn't show the username and image, how is it possible?

Comment: @Generic without security? I configured with spring security

Comment: `I can go insied and do other works in that application, but it doesn't show the username and image, how is it possible?` It is possible because of your security configuration does not care (I think mostly because `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers()` does not restrict it). You should only allow the common URLs like login/logout to be accessed by anyone and all other requests should be authenticated using `AntMatchers`.

Comment: @VPK I included antmachers, but I didn't show here because of easiness. How can I extend timeout period?

Comment: Have a look into this : http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-java-configuration-session-timeout/

Comment: @VPK i think this solves my problem, thank you so much. So I got that there is no relationship between spring security and page session, we have to manually handle it, default value is 30min.

Answer (score -2):

It's called session timeout.

Once the session is timed out, or expired, that's it.

The user doesn't have any session in the server anymore.

The user will have to log-in again.

Try changing the session timeout if you want it to be retained longer.